# OCR on noisy image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a set of images which have one digit on them and a noisy background. I want to identify the digit on the image. I tried these things:

-Google Vision API

-Python tesseract

-OpenCV's Example here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_knn/py_knn_opencv/py_knn_opencv.html#ocr-of-hand-written-digits
but I could not make it work. The vision API was not able to identify the digit itself and tesseract work good for simple/plain backgrounds. My backgrounds are very noisy.

Please suggest some solution. Is this at all possible?

Any links for a head start are also fine, i'll do the exploration.

BTW The image looks like this:[image]

I can share the failed results if required